# Solve Number Puzzle with C and Java

Tags: java, c, algorithm, math, puzzle

This question is translated into English by me from another forum, I found it interesting and then just write a Java solution. And found there's some heap size problem when dealing with large number like 10000000. And I would like to seek some really smart solution compared with my own.

Original Post is in Chinese. And I kind of revised it a little based on my understanding to make it clearer.
http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1637660984282265740.html?sort=6&old=1#here

Below is the puzzle:

```
10000 rows of numbers;
1 row: 2,4,6,8...2K(2K<=10000000); (numbers no repeats for this row)
2 row: 3,3,6,6,9,9...3K(3K<=10000000); (starting from this row, each number repeats 2 times and a multiple which has something to do with row number (2XrowNumber-1) to be specificaly)
3 row: 5,5,10,10,15,15...5K(5K<=10000000);
and following 7K,9K,11K,13K....until
10000 row: 19999,19999,39998,39998....19999K,19999K (19999K<=10000000);
```

That's all the rows to be used in the following part. And now we will calculate the repeat times of numbers starting from row 1 and row 2:

Integer w1 is the repeat times of numbers in row 1 and row2. For example, consider row 1 numbers 2,4,6 and row 2 numbers 3,3,6,6. Then the repeat times up to this point would be 3 since 6 is already in row 1 and appears 2 times in row 2, and 3 appears 2 times in row 2;

```
Integer w2 is the repeat times of numbers in row 1 and row 2 and row 3. 
Integer w3 is the repeat times of numbers in row 1 and row 2 and row 3 and row 4. 
......
Integer w9999 is the repeat times of numbers of row 1,row 2,row 3 .....row 10000.
```

And now print out all integers, w1,w2....w9999;

I have come up with one Java solution, but I have heap size problem since 10000000 is too large and the memory is not enough. So I just use 10000 instead of 10000000, and 10 instead of 10000. Below is what I write in Java. I guess it should be right (if not, please point it out):

```
    Set nums = new HashSet();
    int max = 10000;
    int row = 10;
    for (int i=2;i<=max;i+=2){
        nums.add(new Integer(i));
    }
    int nums_size = nums.size();
    int w = 0;
    for (int i=2;i<=(row);i++){
        int tmp_count = 0;
        int self_count = 0;
        for (int j=(2*i-1);j<=max;j+=(2*i-1)){
            nums.add(new Integer(j));
            self_count++;
            if (nums.size()==nums_size){
                tmp_count++;
            } else {
                nums_size = nums.size();
            }
        }           
        w += tmp_count;
        w += self_count;
        System.out.println("w"+(i-1)+": "+w);
    }
```

My question is

1. How to get a better solution in Java (if any)?
2. How to do it in C
   since there would be no Set class in C as I remember. (importing 3rd
   party library would not be preferred)?

Thanks.

Comment: I am surprised people already give down vote and not even tell me why?

Comment: This is stupid why was this downvoted - maybe someone did not know the answer.

Comment: Is there a pattern for the numbers in each row?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal yes, each number of each row repeat 2 times and basically a multiple of (row number)X2-1

Comment: @Felix What about the first row?  No repeats?

Comment: @SteveP. yea..first row is kind of special, just multiple of 2 and no repeats.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Shouldn't wk = 2k + 1?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I've edited and question and added more of my own understanding. And the first row is kind of special. Could you take a look and see if I've explained myself clearer?

Comment: What you mean by repeat times? Is it the maximum number of occurence of a number? For w1(row1=2,4,6 & row2=3,3,6,6) 2 occurs 1 time, 3 occurs 2 times, 4 occurs 1 time and 6 occurs 3 times, so w1 = 3. Did I get it correctly?

Comment: Based on your confirmation with inankupeli, I can see that w1 = 3 always, as the maximum occurrence in row 1 and 2 is 3 (row 1 doesn't repeat, row 2 every number repeats 2 times.)
When I ran your code I have w1 = 4999. Please explain this point so I can go forward. I already done code in C if w1 = 3

Comment: @lightbringer when I say w1=3, it only counts below 6 (max is 6) as a example. The original post's max is 10000000, my program set max as 10000.

Comment: That makes me confused. If we consider row = 2, max = 1000000 and we calculate w1. Row 1 doesn't repeat so every number occurs only one time. Row 2 repeats 2 times for each number, max occurrence is 2, plus 1 from row 1 is 3. What I'm trying to say is w1 = 3 regardless how big the size is, as long as size > 3. It gets complicated when we calculate w2, w3, etc. It just doesn't make sense to me if w1 > 3, unless I read the requirement wrong.

Comment: The repeat counter w1 is not just the largest repeat time for a specific number. It's the sum of all repeat counter for all numbers of the row defined. For example when we only consider max=12, row1={2,4,6,8,10,12...},row2={3,3,6,6,9,9,12,12...}, the repeat counter w1= 1+2+1+2 = 6 since 3 repeat 1 time, 6 2 times, 9 1 one time, 12 2 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your code. Since it doesn’t use `HashSet`, creating a C version out of it should be no problem anymore.

```
int max = 10000;
int row = 10;
boolean[] seen=new boolean[max+1];
for(int i=2;i<=max;i+=2) seen[i]=true;
int w = 0;
for(int i=2;i<=(row);i++) {
    int self_count = 0;
    for(int j=(2*i-1);j<=max;j+=(2*i-1)) {
        self_count++;
        if(seen[j]) w++; else seen[j]=true;
    }
    w += self_count/2;
    System.out.println("w"+(i-1)+": "+w);
}
```

Comment: I got your idea, and I think this is much better with the use of primitives. Saved a lot of memories. How can I forget to use the basics? Guess I need to learn from the start again. Thanks.

Comment: Do you think there's any faster approach?

Comment: Since each cell from row 3 upwards has the form `(2*r-1)*c` you can skip lots of values for the case “`c` is a multiple of `2*«a previous row»-1)`” for cell values below the maximum of that previous row. Maybe there’s a completely analytical solution but I didn’t dig deep enough into it to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a hint: try using least common multiples.

For example, LCM(5,3)=15, and 15 is the first element in both rows 2 and 3. LCM(2,15)=30, and 30 is the first element in each of the first 3 rows.

You'll eventually get to a row r where the LCM of the first element of the first r rows is beyond 10,000,000, at which point no number shows up each of those rows.

Comment: I guess it would be a little slow if: for every number in every row n(n>2), you need to calculate the least common multiples starting from the first row and every row following until row n-1. Let me know if I am wrong. I am thinking my approach might be quite fast. Don't know if there is any faster approach.

Comment: @Felix You don't need to calculate all those LCMs; LCM(1,2,3,4,...,n) = LCM(LCM(1,2,3,4,...,n-1), n). In other words after getting the LCM of the first r rows, the LCM of the first r+1 rows is one additional LCM operation.

Comment: LCM(2,3)=6; LCM(2,3,5)=LCM(6,5)=30; LCM(2,3,5,7) = LCM(30,7)=210; LCM(2,3,5,7,9) = LCM(210,9)=630; etc...

Comment: Ok..I got a better understanding of what you said. And I'll give a try to see if this approach is faster or not. Thanks for this hint.